# Can I use `which` command for partial match?

Tags: linux, macos, unix, which

I want to find all programs with name like "gcc", "gcc-4.2", "gcc-4.9" and so on.

To find all binaries I tried with `which -a gcc*`.

But "*" is not recognized as 'any' with `which` command.

Is there way to find all programs in PATH environment variable by pattern match?

Comment: In most shells you can simply type `gcc` and press Tab twice to have it autocompleted. Does that work for you or what else is your situation? Meaning, why would you need this?

Comment: In UNIX and Linux, `*` is expanded _before_ the program is executed. That means the interpretation does not depend on the program. In this case, `gcc*` is expanded in the current directory. That's why it doesn't work.

Comment: In OSX default gcc is llvm based that is placed `/usr/bin/gcc`. and by using `brew` installed gcc is placed `/usr/local/bin/gcc-4.x`. I wanted to know there are other `gcc-*` programs. Of course I can use `find`, but it takes some time.

Comment: Thanks MSalters! I was not clear about that point. I thought it depends on programs.

Comment: If you are just looking for the ones in your $PATH, the easiest way is to hit tab twice as @slhck suggested.

Comment: Thanks terdon. I've misread what he wrote. I hit only once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a `BASH` built-in command `compgen` which can be used to list all *commands*, *functions*, *aliases* and *built-ins*.

```
compgen -abck | grep "gcc"
```

---

Parameters: `help compgen`

```
compgen:
[-abcdefgjksuv] 
[-o option]
[-A action]
[-G globpat]
[-W wordlist]
[-F function]
[-C command]
[-X filterpat]
[-P prefix]
[-S suffix]
[word]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick and dirty sample script to do what you want in practice:

```
#!/bin/sh
IFS=:
for i in $PATH; do
    for j in "$i"/$1; do
        [ -f "$j" ] && [ -x "$j" ] && printf '%s\n' "$j"
    done
done
```

Save this as e.g. `whichglob` and make it executable. Sample run:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
$ ./whichglob grep*
/usr/bin/grepdiff
/usr/bin/grep-excuses
/usr/bin/grepjar
/bin/grep
```

Actually all the functionality in `which` (`-a`, exit statuses, multiple file match inputs) can be easily added in this shell script context as well, but I leave that as an exercise for the reader.